# storing kernel core dumps locally on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, kernel, osx-lion, crash-dumps

I've identified a hang in Mac OS X, and I'd like to intentionally panic the kernel and create a dump that I can examine with `gdb` after rebooting.

I read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2118.html) about how to create kernel dumps and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1264/_index.html) about how to generate a non-maskable interrupt, which can force the core dump to be generated. However, the first link tells me I need a "kernel dump server" which will be connected to via the network, and I only have one machine available.

Is there any way to force the kernel dump to be stored locally (on the panicking machine) when the system panics instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > way to force the kernel dump to be stored locally

No, but you can use vm, like vmware or virtual box and use your host machine as dump server if this hang are reproducible.